# Sending request each n seconds with libcurl in c

Tags: c, curl, libcurl

I am trying to figure out how to make a request in c each n seconds. I want it to be asynchronous, meaning the requests are made even if the previous ones have not been responded.

I want to achieve this in order to test a server.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [multi interface](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-multi.html). Add a new handle and start a new request every N seconds and let it take its time. It'll handle "any" amount of simultaneous transfers for you. "any" because there's probably a limit in number of open sockets a process is allowed to use (depending on the environment you want this for).